# Aligning Column Text in MS Word Table Set generated with Powershell

Tags: powershell, text, ms-word, alignment

I am a beginner in Powershell scripting and facing this problem:

I generated a set of tables in a Word document.
At the end I like to align for each table the texts in all cells of the second column vertically centered. I tried to use a code structure like:

```
$document.Tables | ForEach-Object {...}
```

However I find no way to get the hands on the individual column of each table to align the texts.

What would be a possible way?

Answer (score 1):

Found no answer so far. So I ended up with the following:

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$document = $word.documents.open($wordTemplatePath)
...
For ($i = 1; $i -le $document.Tables.Count; $i++) {
    $a = $document.Tables.Item($i).Columns.Item(2).Select() 
    $objSelection = $word.Selection 
    $objSelection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = "wdAlignParagraphCenter" 
    $objSelection.Cells.VerticalAlignment = 1
}
```

Works fine.

Comment: Couldn't find Cells property for horizontal alignment. This method Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To justify the whole table you can use:

```
$table.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment=1
```

To do just a cell:

```
$table.Cell(1,1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment=1
```

Other values are 0 left (default) and 2 right

A combination of these should have your table looking perfect.